# How can I use startService() method from a java class

Tags: android, service

What I am trying to do is that as any incoming call is received I want to start a service ChatHeadService which shows a chat head.

Basically I want to run this command, but as I run the app my app stops at this command.

```
startService(new Intent(getApplication(), ChatHeadService.class));
```

This is my java class CallHelper in which I am using thread to use the `startService()` method.

```
package com.tarun.notifyme2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Helper class to detect incoming and outgoing calls.
 * @author Moskvichev Andrey V.
 *
 */
public class CallHelper extends Activity{
    static String incomingNo;
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=10000;
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT=15000;

    /**
     * Listener to detect incoming calls. 
     */
    private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, final String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                // called when someone is ringing to this phone
                /*
                Intent i; i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager() .getLaunchIntentForPackage
                        ( getBaseContext().getPackageName() ); i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);*/
                Thread thread = new Thread(){
                    private int sleepTime = 400;

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        super.run();
                        try {
                            int wait_Time = 0;

                            while (wait_Time < sleepTime ) {
                                sleep(100);
                                wait_Time += 100;
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(ctx,
                                    "Error Occured Because:" + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        finally {

                        }
                        startService(new Intent(getApplication(), ChatHeadService.class));
                        //ctx.startActivity(new Intent(ctx, ChatHeadService.class).putExtra("number", incomingNumber)
                        //      .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
                        //
                    }
                };
                thread.run();


                incomingNo = incomingNumber;
                Toast.makeText(ctx, 
                        "Incoming no is"+incomingNo+" this",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("check","this no is :"+incomingNo);
                /*
                SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Notify", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String my_no= sp.getString("my_no","");
                */
                String my_no="";

                /*
                Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
                if(b!=null){
                    my_no = b.getString("my_no");
                    sendNotification(my_no);
                }

*/
                Log.i("no check",my_no);


                //Intent i = new Intent(ctx,SendNoti.class);
                //startActivity(i);

                break;
            }
            /*
            Log.i("check",incomingNumber);
            SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("phoneno_info",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putString("incoming",incomingNumber);
            editor.commit();*/

        }
    }


    /**
     * Broadcast receiver to detect the outgoing calls.
     */
    public class OutgoingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public OutgoingReceiver() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            /*
            Intent i; i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager() .getLaunchIntentForPackage
                    ( getBaseContext().getPackageName() ); i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
            */

            Toast.makeText(ctx, 
                    "Outgoing: "+number, 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private static Context ctx;
    private TelephonyManager tm;
    private CallStateListener callStateListener;

    private OutgoingReceiver outgoingReceiver;


    public CallHelper(Context ctx) {
        this.incomingNo = incomingNo;
        this.ctx = ctx;


        callStateListener = new CallStateListener();
        outgoingReceiver = new OutgoingReceiver();
/*
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("phoneno_info",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
        e.putString("incoming",incomingNo);
        e.commit();
        /*
        Intent i = new Intent(ctx,SendNoti.class);
        i.putExtra("incoming",incomingNo);*/
//      startActivity(i);

    }

    /**
     * Start calls detection.
     */
    public void start() {
        tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
        ctx.registerReceiver(outgoingReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    /**
     * Stop calls detection.
     */
    public void stop() {
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        ctx.unregisterReceiver(outgoingReceiver);
    }
    private void sendNotification(String phone_no){
        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            HttpURLConnection conn;
            URL url = null;

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String login_url = "https://notify-me-rajhanssingh.c9users.io/notify_on_incoming.php";

                try {
                    // Enter URL address where your php file resides
                    url = new URL(login_url);

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return "Check your internet connection";
                }
                try {
                    // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                    // setDoInput and setDoOutput method depict handling of both send and receive
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);

                    // Append parameters to URL

                    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                            .appendQueryParameter("my_no", params[0]);
                    String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

                    // Open connection for sending data
                    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                            new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                    writer.write(query);
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                    os.close();
                    conn.connect();

                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    return "Error occured";
                }

                try {

                    int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                    // Check if successful connection made
                    if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                        // Read data sent from server
                        InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                        String line;

                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            result.append(line);
                        }

                        // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                        return(result.toString());

                    }else{

                        return(" Notification was not sent");
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return "Error occured";
                } finally {
                    conn.disconnect();
                }
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                /*
                Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, SendNoti.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                ctx.startActivity(intent);*/
            }
        }
        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(phone_no);
    }

}
```

My ChatHeadService.class is as follows:

```
package com.tarun.notifyme2;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ChatHeadService extends Service {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private ImageView chatHead;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        int res = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return res;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        chatHead = new ImageView(this);
        chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.app_icon);

        params= new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;
        chatHead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ChatHeadService.this,SendNoti.class);
                startActivity(i);
                stopSelf();
            }
        });

        //this code is for dragging the chat head
        chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;


            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = params.x;
                    initialY = params.y;
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    params.x = initialX
                            + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                    params.y = initialY
                            + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (chatHead != null)
            windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the error message I am getting

```
08-12 00:49:51.858 22016-22016/com.tarun.notifyme2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.tarun.notifyme2, PID: 22016
                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
                                                                     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
                                                                     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4286)
                                                                     at com.tarun.notifyme2.CallHelper$CallStateListener$1.run(CallHelper.java:73)
                                                                     at com.tarun.notifyme2.CallHelper$CallStateListener.onCallStateChanged(CallHelper.java:82)
                                                                     at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$1.handleMessage(PhoneStateListener.java:293)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Comment: What does your LogCat say?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I have added the error msg in my question +Casey B and +Code-Apprentice